# How do I fix Not Serializable: System.Savepoint error on custom Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, savepoint

I am trying to use a Savepoint to rollback changes on a Visualforce Page (only when there is an Exception).

I am using a custom controller with a custom save method (triggered by a button).

When I click the save button, the page disappears and an error message shows on the screen:

```
Not Serializable: System.Savepoint
```

I can't find any information on what this error means. Can anyone help me understand what this error means?

Comment: I was able to fix the error. I was declaring the savepoint variable as a member of the controller class `public SavePoint sp{get;set;}` then assigning `sp = Database.setSavepoint();` in the save method where it would be used.

I switched to defining `sp` within the save method, and the error went away.

I still don't understand what the error `Not Serializable: System.Savepoint` means, or how it applies to this situation.

Will someone please clarify the meaning of this error and why this solution worked?

Answer (score 2):

Certain types of data don't make sense across multiple transactions. SavePoint is one of those data types. If you are able to serialize a SavePoint, you'd be able to call `Database.rollback` on a previously committed and completed transaction, which is illegal in most, if not all, database engines. Once a transaction has its final commit, it cannot be rolled back. Salesforce enforces this by marking SavePoint as not serializable. This means you can't convert to/from a SavePoint in JSON, you can't save it in the Visualforce view state, and you can't serialize it as part of asynchronous code, such as a Batchable, Queueable, or Schedulable class.

Answer (score 1):

The controller's state is sent to the browser to maintain it between calls to server-side processing. This is known as serialization.

When the server is called the state is sent back to it and deserialized to make it appear that the controller was there, waiting, on the server all that time when in fact it was not.

Not all objects that Salesforce exposes to Apex can be serialized. A save point is one such object (as are things like SObject schema descriptors etc.).

When you directly include any properties or attributes on your controller class, these become part of the state and must, therefore, support serialization and deserialization.

Make sure not to include these non-serializable objects as such properties/attributes and you will be fine. Instantiate them where you need them, as local variables.

Comment: Between you and fox, you've pretty much covered what I was going to say. I might've gone into a bit more about serialization (a general process for transforming objects/data so it can be transmitted/stored, with the intent to reconstruct it later), but I think it's fine to just leave it in this comment.

Comment: Also, another way to prevent something from getting into the viewstate is to use the `transient` keyword/modifier when defining a variable/property. That wouldn't be the right solution for this particular scenario, but it can be a useful tool. The `transient` modifier also prevents things from being picked up when using `JSON.serialize()` and `JSON.deserialize()`.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I did not mention it. Yes, it can sometimes be handy, especially when used with a property you instantiate if required in the getter, but that's for other scenarios.